# Python candlestick chart can not show

Tags: python, matplotlib, quandl

I executed the code below and no errors showed in the process, but plt.show() could not work and showed nothing in the end! I'm confused and want to know why......

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import quandl

df = quandl.get("EOD/AAPL", authtoken="fzTPb-TWywaPkbdAS1VF")

df['Date'] = df.index.map(mdates.date2num)

ohlc = df[['Date','Open','High','Low','Close']]

f1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))

candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=.6, colorup='green', colordown='red')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to tell us *where* and *how*  you run this code.

Comment: the code was run by jupyter notebook 5.5.0, line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jupyter notebook it makes sense to define a backend, e.g. `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook`. 
When then running your code in a singe cell it should show you the plot.

If you need to run it in seperate cells, `plt.show()` will not know what to show from previous cells. So in that case, state the figure instead,

```
f1
```

to show the figure `f1`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestions! The figure showed successfully in jupyter notebook!